# How to show or prove equivalence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I have this relation : 
for all integers  m and n so : 
m R n ⇔ m ≡ n mod(3)

How can I show that R is an equivalence relation

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: Do you know the properties R needs to have to be called an equivalence? There are 3. Which ones are problematic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

**General:** First note that $a\equiv b\pmod{3}\iff a-b\equiv0\pmod{3}\iff3|(a-b)$.

**Reflexive:** Everything divides zero so $3|(a-a)$ which implies that...

**Symmetric:** If $aRb$ then $3|(a-b)$. What can you say about $b-a$?

**Transitive:** If $aRb$ and $bRc$ then $3|(a-b)$ and $3|(c-b)$. Can you find a proof that this necessarily implies that $3|(c-a)$?

Comment: Can you give me more clarification about it or a full resolving. thx :)

Comment: @AosKhalifa is there a particular point you need clarification on?

Comment: In fact, this question is a part of my assignment in the university and i tried to solve it but i couldn't so I need someone to tell me precisely how can I solve it.

Comment: @AosKhalifa an equivalence relation must be reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Once you have shown that the relation satisfies those properties you are done. Is there a particular one of those three properties you are having problems with proving? I will explain in more detail if you want, but if this is an assignment I would encourage you to spend some more time on it yourself.

Comment: OK, could you explain to me what is mod? and how m R n ⇔ m ≡ n mod(3) is read? and how you converted it to be 3|(a-b) :).

Comment: @AosKhalifa [$a\pmod{n}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) means remainder of $a$ upon division by $n$ and is read "a mod n". So $4\pmod{3}$ would be 1. The relation you presented says two numbers are related if their remainder upon division by 3 is the same. Now, two numbers have the same remainder upon division by 3 if their difference is divisible by 3 which is my general hint.

Comment: finally, it has been solved :). Thanks @E.O .

Comment: @AosKhalifa glad I could help :)